# Is it possible to write typescript parser using typescript Template Literal types?

Tags: typescript, metaprogramming

We have seen types for parsing [json and sql queries](https://dev.to/phenomnominal/i-need-to-learn-about-typescript-template-literal-types-51po), but what about writing a Template Literal type parser for typescript itself?

```
type isValid = TypeScript<`function fooBar(): void {}`>

//   ^ must be true


type isValid = TypeScript<`type Foo = Bar`>

//   ^ must be false
```

Comment: Please keep in mind, that TS has his own recursion limits